# Is "as though" exactly the same as "as if" when expressing a subjunctive mood?

Tags: word-choice

For example:

> After the operation, their dog walked around on all four legs, as if nothing had happened to it!

Can "as though" be used to replace "as if" in the sentence?

Is "as though" exactly the same as "as if" in all circumstances?

Comment: not to be picky, but there is one instance where it is **not** interchangeable. The sarcastic exclamatory "AS IF!" which is meant to shun someone's words. In AmE, I would consider this most popular among teenage girls.

Comment: That's interesting! I'm wondering if there are any examples of using “As if!” in certain conversational context?

Comment: For example, you ask someone to loan you a million dollars. They may say "AS IF!" - meaning, "No, I will not and I know you wish I would"

Comment: Thanks a lot.It's like saying "As if I would!", isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, but at the same time, avoiding the question. Slang dictionary: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=as+if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As if/as though

These phrases have a similar meaning, hence interchangeable. However, the phrase "as if" is more common than the phrase "as though".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and yes; it's a matter of preference.

Duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134575/analogy-as-if-vs-as-though), but I don't have enough rep to mark as such.

Comment: Why do I still feel it sounds a little awkward by using “as though” in the OP's sentence？

Comment: It might well sound awkward to you; there are certainly valid constructs that I never use because they sound strange to me. You may not be in the habit of using "as though," or you may have subconsciously decided to only use it in certain contexts. I would probably choose "as if" myself in this case, but "as though" wouldn't attract my attention if it were written as such.